# Changing a simple parameter breaks the MySql Query when is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have changed a query in my code because I wanted the users to select a specific value from a dropdown list, rather than a free text search. In this case I have to adjust for the fact that if the user does not select a specific value, I still want all the relevant results. After the change, the query returns No Results. 
I am very puzzled because I have used a similar query many times.
Here is the original Query that works:

```
SELECT `companies`.`name`, `companies`.`website`,`country`.`country_name`, 
        `company_sector`.`notes`, `sector`.`sector_name`, 
        FORMAT(`financials`.`revenues`,0), 
        FORMAT(`financials`.`ebitda`,0) 
FROM { oj `seta`.`company_sector` AS `company_sector` 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`companies` AS `companies` ON `company_sector`.`company_id` = `companies`.`company_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`country` AS `country` ON `country`.`country_id` = `companies`.`country_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`financials` AS `financials` ON `financials`.`company_id` = `companies`.`company_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` ON `contacts`.`contact_id` = `companies`.`seta_id` 
    }, 
`seta`.`sector` AS `sector` 
WHERE 
      (
        (`company_sector`.`sector_id` = `sector`.`sector_id`)
      AND 
        (`companies`.`name` LIKE '%".$query_name."%')
      AND 
        (`company_sector`.`notes` LIKE '%".$query_product."%')
      AND 
        (`country`.`country_name` LIKE '%".$query_country."%')
      AND 
        (`sector`.`sector_name` LIKE '%".$query_sector."%')
```

While this is the new query that doesnt work. As you can see, I changed only the last 2 lines.

```
SELECT `companies`.`name`, `companies`.`website`, `country`.`country_name`, 
        `company_sector`.`notes`, `sector`.`sector_name`, 
        FORMAT(`financials`.`revenues`,0), 
        FORMAT(`financials`.`ebitda`,0) 
FROM { oj `seta`.`company_sector` AS `company_sector` 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`companies` AS `companies` ON `company_sector`.`company_id` = `companies`.`company_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`country` AS `country` ON `country`.`country_id` = `companies`.`country_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`financials` AS `financials` ON `financials`.`company_id` = `companies`.`company_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` ON `contacts`.`contact_id` = `companies`.`seta_id` }, `seta`.`sector` AS `sector` 
WHERE 
     ( 
      (`company_sector`.`sector_id` = `sector`.`sector_id`)
      AND 
      (`companies`.`name` LIKE '%".$query_name."%')
      AND 
      (`company_sector`.`notes` LIKE '%".$query_product."%')
      AND
       (
        (`company_sector`.`sector_id` = ".$query_sector.") 
        OR 
        (".$query_sector." IS NULL)
       )
      ) 
       ORDER BY `financials`.`revenues` ASC
```

Can you please help?
Thanks
Regards
Tommaso

Comment: _"doesnt work"_ means what? What mysqli_error do you get? What is the result of the concatanated query?

Comment: `".$query_sector." IS NULL` this is your issue, Try checking your variables through php, mysql can only check for column values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break query to sections and append your filter values if filter is selected. see the example below.

```
$query = "SELECT `companies`.`name`, `companies`.`website`, `country`.`country_name`, `company_sector`.`notes`, `sector`.`sector_name`, FORMAT(`financials`.`revenues`,0), FORMAT(`financials`.`ebitda`,0) FROM { oj `seta`.`company_sector` AS `company_sector` RIGHT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`companies` AS `companies` ON `company_sector`.`company_id` = `companies`.`company_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`country` AS `country` ON `country`.`country_id` = `companies`.`country_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`financials` AS `financials` ON `financials`.`company_id` = `companies`.`company_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` ON `contacts`.`contact_id` = `companies`.`seta_id` }, `seta`.`sector` AS `sector` WHERE 
             ( 
              (`company_sector`.`sector_id` = `sector`.`sector_id`)
              AND 
              (`companies`.`name` LIKE '%".$query_name."%')
              AND 
              (`company_sector`.`notes` LIKE '%".$query_product."%')";

//check if filter is selected. 
if(!empty($query_sector)){
        $query .= " AND `company_sector`.`sector_id` = ".$query_sector; //append to main query.
}

$query .= " ORDER BY `financials`.`revenues` ASC";
```

Comment: Worked Great! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming an empty string matches `IS NULL` with this line:

```
(".$query_sector." IS NULL)
```

That will never resolve to true.

What you mean is:

```
(".$query_selector." = '')
```